# How to expand $(x+ty)^{T}A(x+ty)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to expand the expression: $$(x+ty)^{T}A(x+ty),$$
with $x,y$ being vectors and $A$ a matrix. All I know is the distributed law, $(A+B)C = AC+BC$. Can someone explain how to arrive to the following expanded expression? 
$$(x+ty)^{T}A(x+ty) = x^{T}Ax+ty^{T}Ax + ty^{T}A^{T}x+t^{2}y^{T}Ay.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of the vectors $\mathbf{x}$ & $\mathbf{y}$ as matrices too, of size $n \times 1$. Does that make your life easier? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They use linearity of $\;A\;$ **and** of transposing:

$$(x+ty)^TA(x+ty)=(x^T+ty^T)A(x+ty)=x^TA(x+ty)+ty^TA(x+ty)=$$

$$=x^T(Ax+tAy)+ty^T(Ax+tAy)=x^TAx+tx^TAy+ty^TAx+t^2y^TAy$$

Comment: Thanks mate!this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the distributive law to expand and get
$$
(x + ty)^TA(x + ty) = x^TAx + x^T A (ty) + (ty)^TAx + (ty)^TA(ty)
$$
Now, because $t$ is a scalar, and because $u^Tv = v^T u$, we can write
$$
x^TAx + x^T A (ty) + (ty)^TAx + (ty)^TA(ty) =\\
x^TAx + t x^T (Ay) + t y^T A x + t^2 y^T A y =\\
x^TAx + t (Ay)^T x + t y^T A x + t^2 y^T A y =\\
x^TAx + t y^T A^T x + t y^T A x + t^2 y^T A y
$$